# calculating percentage change in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to calculate the percentage change of a stock. The loop finds the current price and price 1 and 3 months later, but when i try to calculate the percentage change I get this error: `Error in data.frame(CurrentPrice = current_price, Price1MonthLater = price_1_month_later,  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`

```
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

getSymbols("EQNR.OL", from = "2018-1-1", to = "2022-1-1", auto.assign = TRUE)

sma <- cbind(EQNR.OL$EQNR.OL.Close, SMA(EQNR.OL$EQNR.OL.Close, 50))
colnames(sma) <- c("EQNR.OL", "SMA(50)")


# Finn indeks for alle kryssinger opp
cross_above_points <- ifelse(Cl(EQNR.OL) > sma[, "SMA(50)"], 1, 0)

# Finn indeks for alle datoene når aksjekursen stiger over 50SMA for første gang
cross_above_indices <- which(diff(cross_above_points) == 1)

# Lag en tom liste for å lagre alle datoene etter hver kryssing opp
all_dates_after_crossings <- list()

# Loop gjennom indeksene og lagre alle datoene etter hver kryssing opp
for (cross_index in cross_above_indices) {
  
  # Finn indeksene der EQNR.OL er større enn den gjeldende indeksen
  dates_after_crossing <- index(EQNR.OL)[cross_index]
  
  # Konverter datoen til Date-format
  dates_after_crossing <- as.Date(dates_after_crossing)
  
  # Legg til datoene og prosentuell prisforandring i 1 og 3 måneder etter hver kryssing opp i listen
  all_dates_after_crossings <- append(all_dates_after_crossings, list(dates_after_crossing))
  
}
# Lage en tabell/dataframe for å legge resultatene inn
Tabell <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character()),
                     CurrentPrice = double(),
                     Price1MonthLater = double(),
                     Price3MonthsLater = double(),
                     PercentageChange1Month = double(),
                     PercentageChange3Months = double())


# Loop gjennom hver dato i listen
for (i in seq_along(all_dates_after_crossings)) {
  # Hent ut data for gjeldende dato
  date <- all_dates_after_crossings[[i]][1]
  current_price <- Cl(EQNR.OL)[which(index(EQNR.OL) == date)]
  
  # Pris 1 og 3 måneder senere
  price_1_month_later_index <- which(index(EQNR.OL) == date) + 20
  price_3_months_later_index <- which(index(EQNR.OL) == date) + 60
  
  price_1_month_later <- Cl(EQNR.OL)[price_1_month_later_index]
  price_3_months_later <- Cl(EQNR.OL)[price_3_months_later_index]
  
  # Beregn prosentvis avkastning
  percentage_change_1_month <- ((Cl(EQNR.OL)[price_1_month_later_index])-(Cl(EQNR.OL)[which(index(EQNR.OL) == date)]))/(Cl(EQNR.OL)[which(index(EQNR.OL) == date)])*100
  percentage_change_3_months <- ((Cl(EQNR.OL)[price_3_months_later_index])-(Cl(EQNR.OL)[which(index(EQNR.OL) == date)]))/(Cl(EQNR.OL)[which(index(EQNR.OL) == date)])*100
  
  Tabell <- rbind(Tabell, data.frame(CurrentPrice = current_price,
                                     Price1MonthLater = price_1_month_later,
                                     Price3MonthsLater = price_3_months_later,
                                     PercentageChange1Month = percentage_change_1_month,
                                     PercentageChange3Months = percentage_change_3_months))
}



# Sett riktige navn på kolonnene
names(Tabell) <- c("Current Price", "Price 1 month later", "Price 3 months later", "Percentage change 1 month later", "Percentage change 3 months later")


# Fjern eventuelle duplikater
Tabell <- unique(Tabell)

# Vis tabellen
print(Tabell)
```

I have tried to just put in a number for `percentage_change_1_month` and `percentage_change_3_months`, the code then works but I get the number in all of the rows and in the correct column in the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)

tq_get("EQNR.OL", from = "2018-1-1", to = "2022-1-1") %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close,
            mutate_fun = SMA,
            n = 50, col_rename = "sma") %>% 
  mutate(cross = if_else(close > sma, 1, 0), 
         first_cross = cross - lag(cross),
         price_1m = lag(close, 20), 
         price_3m = lag(close, 60)) %>% 
  filter(first_cross == 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("price"), ~ (.x / close) - 1, .names = "{.col}_change"))
```